# How Many Unique Audio Channels Are Supported In Spatial Audio?

Tags: audio, apple-music

I hear the term Dolby Atmos mixed with Spatial Audio. Dolby Atmos has 7.2 channels I think. Does that mean Spatial Audio has 7.2 channels?

Comment: What is your source? What is 1/5 of a channel?

Comment: @SolarMike AFAIK the number after the dot refers to the number of subwoofers, i.e. a 2.0 system is a standard two-speaker setup and 2.1 is with a dedicated subwoofer. 5.1 usually has front left, center, front right, back left and back right and a subwoofer,...

Comment: @SolarMike Yes what X_841 said. The ".2" refers to the number of dedicated subwoofers. I seem to be mistaken about the number of channels Atmos supports. Wikipedia indicates there are 128 channels. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Atmos. Still curious about how many channels Spatial audio supports. I don't know if its "tricking" my ears into thinking there are more than 2 channels or whether it really does support 7.2 individual channels.

Comment: @pmagunia From what I've read so far the 128 channels/objects is only for cinema and master. For consumer use it's limited to 5.1 (ac3) or 7.1 (eac3). Spatial Audio is Apple's renderer for Dolby Atmos, which takes in eac3, decodes it to objects, and renders it to 2 channels (binaural) for your headphone using its own algorithm which is different from Dolby's. What you get over bluetooth is still the standard 2-channel aac.